# All users can't login

Tags: authentication-authorization, 10

After migrating from Drupal 9 to Drupal 10 all users can't login. I tried:

- Removing settings.php and adding a new version
- Emptying the sessions table in the database
- Clearing cache, updating database
- Clearing cache in browser
- Using different browser
- Saving the users account

Nothing works, the only this that does work is resetting the password. But its extra work for the user to do this so I'm still looking for a global fix so I can fix it for everyone at once.

Anyone with this same problem? Or a suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: Is this https://www.drupal.org/node/3322420?

Comment: Thanks! Just got the same link from a Slack group. I'll try. It looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.drupal.org/node/3322420

> Password hashing is changed
>
> When a site updates to Drupal 10.1.0 or later, a database-update
> function installs the Password Compatibility module. This allows
> existing users to use their credentials. If the module is not
> installed, existing users can login by requesting a new password.
>
> The first time an existing user logs in, a new hash is and saved to
> the database. From then on, the user can log in with the same
> credentials whether this module is installed or not.

Comment: Indeed, release notes (https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/10.1.0) are immediately helpful when upgrading.